# codeigniter form validation and multiple views accessing same function

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have 3 different views that have to access the same function from the same controller to validate their forms. In my validation function if the validation fails at various steps it sends back a message to the view listed in the function. Problem being I have to have three different functions all doing the same thing just with different returned views. Is there any way in codeigniter to send the user back to a view with data without calling the actual view, possibly a `$this -> load -> view('$this_referring_view);` option. I can't seem to find a variable that passes the referring view.

```
if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
    $data['failMsg2'] = "failed";
    $this -> load -> view('home', $data);
} else …
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand, so I'll try to help by hitting higher-level issues.

> I have 3 different views that have to access the same function from the same controller to validate their forms

Then you should move that validation into an extended form_validation class that includes your new validation rule.

> Is there a way to send a user back to a view without actually calling the view?

You don't call views, you call controllers which in turn load views (through the output buffer). If you'd like to just load the HTML from a view, just pass a 3rd parameter of `false` to the `view()` method.

`$html = $this->load->view('view', $data, FALSE);`

A typical form validation process works as follows:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
  // Form validation failed, either because it's an initial laod
  // or because they actually failed to pass validation
  $this->load->view('view', $data);   
}

// Form validation has passed, redirect the user
redirect('view');
```

Any error messages would be set by the form validation class directly, not as a result of a failed validation (since this will occur upon initial load).

Note: Take the actual code examples with a grain of salt, I haven't touched CodeIgniter in years.

Comment: I understand all this. And I have all of that working already. The main thing I am trying to accomplish is when the validation passes or fails in that function, that instead of `$this->load->view('view name')` that there be a way to call `$this->load->view('the referring views name here')` as there is many different levels of validation going on, checking if database for info, checking validation rules, etc…. not just a simple pass fail. Again everything is working just trying to cut 100 lines of code to 33

Comment: sorry as well the referring views name would be a variable and not hard coded. This is the main thing I am trying to accomplish.